# constructor for 'SiteList' must explicitly initialize the member 'sites' which does not have a default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class called SiteList that contains an array that contains Site objects. But when I compile, I get an error that reads,

> error: constructor for 'SiteList' must explicitly initialize the member 'sites' which does not have a default constructor

Can anybody help me out?

Here is my header file SiteList.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Site.h"
using namespace std;

class SiteList {
public:
    int getLength();
    string checkStatus(int, int);
    void printList();
    void inputData(Site);
    SiteList(Site);
private:
    Site sites[600];
    int arrayCounter;
};
```

And my constructor (just my constructor)

```
SiteList::SiteList(Site site){
    sites[600];
    arrayCounter = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I do not understand why the constructor has parameter `Site site` that is not used?

```
SiteList::SiteList(Site site){
    sites[600];
    arrayCounter = 0;
}
```

Also this statement

```
sites[600];
```

means access to element of the array sites with index 600. It is obvious that it has no any sense.

As for the error message then it is clear enough:class Site has no default constructor. What do you not understand in this phrase?

When this constructor is called it tries to create data member `Site sites[600];` calling the default constructor of type Site for each element of the array. But the class has no default constructor.

From the C++ Standard:

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument.

You should provide the default constructor for class Site.

Some additional remarks

Member functions `getLength` and `printList` should be defined as constatn functions

```
int getLength() const;
void printList() const;
```

instead of the magic number 600 it is better to introduce a symbolic constant. For example

```
private:
    static const int N = 600;
    Site sites[N];
    int arrayCounter;
};
```

Comment: She/He should only add the constructor to Site, if it is a good design choice.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, the line

```
sites[600];
```

doesn't do what you think it does (probably). It refers to the element at index 600 of the `sites` array, and doesn't do anything with it. (Also, it's undefined behaviour, since the array only has indices 0 through 599.)

The compilation error arises because the `Site` class, presumably, has no default constructor. If a class has no default constructor, then the compiler doesn't know how to initialize it unless you explicitly provide constructor arguments. And yet, every time you instantiate a `SiteList`, you create an array of `Site` objects, so the compiler *has* to know how to initialize `Site` objects.

The solution is to add a default constructor for `Site`, *i.e.*,

```
Site::Site() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Site::Site(int siteID, string siteName, string status, string remediationStatus, string typeOfContamination, int Xcord, int Ycord){
    this->siteID = siteID;
    this->siteName = siteName;
    this->status = status;
    this->remediationStatus = remediationStatus;
    this->typeOfContamination = typeOfContamination;
    this->Xcord = Xcord;
    this->Ycord = Ycord;
}

Comment: @tokimoto That's not a default constructor. A default constructor takes zero arguments.